# Python library for writing JSON piecemeal

Tags: library, python, json, serialization

I'm searching for a Python 2 library for serializing values as JSON that does not require the entire value to be calculated & in memory before serialization.  I'd prefer something streaming/event-based (like [ijson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/) but in reverse), but I'd also settle for something that can intelligently serialize generators as lists.

Simple example use:

```
with open('outfile.json', 'w') as outfile:
    with magic_json_library.begin_object(outfile) as obj:
        obj.set_key("foo", 3.14)
        obj.begin_list(key="stuff")
        for item in retrieve_values_from_large_database():
            obj.append(item)
        obj.end_list()
        obj.begin_object(key="about_stuff")
        for field, value in retrieve_mapping_from_large_website():
            obj.add_key(field, value)
        obj.end_object()
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON's encoding rules are really, really simple. The majority of the effort involved in writing a JSON codec is to deal with the arbitrarily-recursive nature of objects and with organizing the representation of the output (e.g. sorting the keys, etc.).

But in your case, with a streaming output engine, much (if not all) of that complexity goes away, and all that's left is basic formatting and correctness.

I imagine you could write such a tool in under 100 lines. Functions like `begin_list` are more-or-less as simple as `print "["`, plus some state maintenance for accuracy guarantees. The data types are simple to represent, the escaping rules straight-forward. There's not really anything to it.

Have a look at [encoder.py from simplejson](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson/blob/master/simplejson/encoder.py) to get an idea of all that goes in to writing a full-featured JSON encoder. You'll be surprised at how little there is to do.